# Problems with .place in GUI with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

Usually this format works for all of my programs but for some reason its not working right now

```
from Tkinter import *

class gui1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.widget_display()

    def widget_display(self):
        a1 = Label(self, text = 'yeah')
        a1.place(x = 0 , y =10)

root = Tk()
app = gui1(root)
app.pack()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.mainloop()
```

I want to know why it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given your frame a size, and you aren't using a geometry manager in a way that causes it to grow, so by default it will be 1x1. The code is working, it's just that your label is inside a single pixel. This is one of the reasons that place isn't recommended -- it forces you to be explicit about the size and placement of everything.

If you give your frame an explicit width and height, or if you pack it so that it grows to fill the whole window, your label will show up.